# Laravel unit test using Liquibase

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, tdd, liquibase, lumen

In my Laravel project, I'm using Liquibase, which is a database-independent library, so there won't be a migration file.

Now that I cannot write unit tests without migration, I was wondering if any one has done unit tests using Liquibase.

Answer (score 0):

We have a few articles and some documentation about exactly that! Here you go:

**Articles**

- https://www.liquibase.org/community/contribute/unit-testing
- https://www.liquibase.com/blog/unit-testing-database-access-layer
- https://www.liquibase.com/blog/test-automation-framework

**Documentation**

- https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-test-harness

**Free Course with Liquibase University**

- https://learn.liquibase.com/catalog/info/id:130